# How can I achieve a camera follow exactly like Temple Run in Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

When player moves forward the camera should follow except when player moves in left and right direction. Also when player turns 90 degrees following the path like in temple run the camera should follow the player by turning 90 degrees smoothly. How can I achieve that? Can anyone please provide a C# script?

Answer (score 0):

If you follow these steps it should work:

1: add an empty gameObject called "CamPoint" on your player and position it where you want the camera.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIfbe.png

2: make a new script on your camera, call it "CameraFollow" and put this code in there:

```
    public Transform camPoint;
public Transform player;
public float heightFromGround;
float yPos;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(player.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
    {
        yPos = hit.point.y;
    }

    transform.position = new Vector3(camPoint.position.x, yPos + heightFromGround, camPoint.position.z);
    transform.LookAt(player.position);
}
```

3: Set the height from ground to the height of the camera.

4: Drag the CamPoint object to the CamPoint slot on the camera and the Player object to the player slot.

And now you are done, Hope this helps you!